# Tracking Microsoft Lync Video Call

Tags: lync

I'm trying to track the usage of Microsoft Lync 2010 video call. It would be involving data collection such as involved users, date, time and duration of the video call. Is it possible to create a WPF application that tracks this all the time from the client side?

I'm well aware of the conversation history in the Outlook folder, but I'm not part of the IT department and I dare not to tinker with the database in the server which I am not familiar with. I just wish to collect this piece of information from my own PC. The objective of this is just to know how many times video call was used recently, who are the users involved in incoming and outgoing video calls, and the time when it was being used. Some hints will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done on the topic?

Comment: more or less about lync 2010 sdk and also on how to detect incoming calls. is it possible to determine when the call is terminated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can do this, using the [Lync Client SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lync_by_lync/archive/2010/10/05/introducing-the-microsoft-lync-client-platform-sdk.aspx).

Have a look at this blog post: http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2012/06/answering-the-call-accepting-incoming-calls-in-lync-client-sdk/

The post is actually about how to answer incoming calls, but it explains how to track Conversations starting, which is what you'll need to do.

You'll also need to track the Conversation ending, or Terminating. Both of these are events on the Conversation object. Conversations have a unique ConversationID so you could store each new Conversation in a Enumerable and maybe use a stopwatch or timestamp to capture the length. (I don't think that the Conversation object has a property for conversation length)

You say that you want to track only video calls. Again, check that blog post. It may be that only want to start capturing information when the call is escalated to video, but that's up to you.

I'm going to put on my todo list to mock up a working example of something like this, but I really can't promise anything. If I get around to it then I'll post an update here.  Update: blog post here: http://thoughtstuff.co.uk/2013/01/tracking-lync-conversations-in-code/

Happy New Year

Comment: Merci! Thanks for even replying to this post. Great site, kinda weird that I didn't even come across this page despite some heavy Google searching for the past week. Well thanks for pointing out what I should look for. Definitely looking forward to your example if you have time for it. Anyway, Happy New Year to you too.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a link to a blog post which might help you.

Comment: Well, this gave me a good start to a brand new year, Thanks a whole lot!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a little bit confused. `!=ModalityState.Disconnected` is used to check that it's not an IM-only call right? Does it also means the call is incoming? I noticed you mentioned that it works with incoming calls, so I wasn't sure about that. Sorry if this sounds silly.

Comment: Yes. For that Modality (the AV one), if the state isn't Disconnected, it must be something else. That can be one of several things, like Connecting, Connected, Initialising, etc etc but Disconnected is the state used if the AV session isn't being used at all. So, it's not quite true to say that it's not an IM-only call, just that it is now a AV call. (for instance, an IM call with desktop sharing wouldn't count as you're only checking the state of the AudioVideo modality)

Comment: Also, it does work with Incoming calls and Outgoing just the same. You can differentiate between them if you need to by looking at the different states of the AudioVideo modality. I can't quite remember, but the modality is put into a different state for incoming and outgoing calls.

Comment: I know that `ModalityState.Notified` is for incoming call, while `ModalityState.Connecting` is for outgoing call. 
However, when checking whether the conversation has been upscaled, the ModalityState should be Disconnected. So for this part, ModalityState cannot be used to check the direction of the call? This issue arises since I cannot save the direction of call before determining whether the call is AV. So sorry for the trouble.